# generate epoch time in gatling script at dynamicaally

Tags: load-testing, gatling

I have POST request need to pass the epoch time dynamically. How to generate epoch time and pass it in the request body?

.body(StringBody("""{"window.performance.timing":{"navigationStart":1523957616037,"redirectStart":0,"redirectEnd":0,"fetchStart":1523957616037,"domainLookupStart":1523957616037

Answer (score 0):

You need to use session expression (a function of type `Session => T`) to build body:

```
.body(StringBody(_ => s"""... ${System.currentTimeMillis()} ...""" ))
```

This way that expression will be evaluated separately for each user in simulation.

Also many other methods in Gatling DSL can either take "normal" parameter which is evaluated once for whole scenario or session expressions which are evaluated separately for each user.